# AJAX запрос символ "_"

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Отправляю такой запрос

```
$.ajax({
 type: "POST",
 url: "http://apitest.jde.ru:8000/calculator/price?from=1125899906842720&to=1125899906842638&weight=14&volume=0.05&quantity=1&pickup=0&delivery=0&declared=2777&services=DVAL",
 jsonpCallback: 'jsonCallback',
 contentType: "application/json",
 dataType: 'jsonp',
 success: function(data2) {
  console.log(data);
 } 
})
```

но если смотреть в дебагере, то запрос при отправке уходит вот такой

```
http://apitest.jde.ru:8000/calculator/price?from=1125899906842720&to=1125899906842638&weight=14&volume=0.05&quantity=1&pickup=0&delivery=0&declared=2777&services=DVAL&callback=jsonCallback&_=1496041705297
```

До этого не возникало никаких особых проблем, но сервер ругается что параметр `_` не найден. Что это за параметр _=1496041705297? Для чего он передается ajax? И можно ли как то обойтись без него?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Это timestamp, он там для того, чтоб сервер отдавал не кешированые данные, а свежие. Лушим решением будет решить эту проблему на серверной стороне

Из доков жуквери:

> **dataType**
>
> ---
>
> ...
>
> "jsonp": Загружает данные в JSON используя при помощи формата ....
>
> .... Выключает
> кэширование путем добавления параметра "_=[TIMESTAMP]" к URL адресу,
> даже если значение параметра cache равно true.

Comment: А можно ли как то отправить без данного параметра? Ибо доступа на сервер нет. И тех.поддержка не отвечает вовсе.

Comment: попробуйте убрать параметры  `jsonpCallback: 'jsonCallback',` и ` dataType: 'jsonp',`

Comment: Пробовал без этого параметра. Он пропадает только при условии что если уберу dataType: 'jsonp', 
Но без этого параметра я не получу ответ. Т.к. запрос кроссбраузерный